# Array Elements does not get displayed in the select box in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, drop-down-menu

I am adding new elements in array and trying to set all those elements dynamically to a select box in java script, but on every refresh of the  browser select box does get empty again.but the list shown outside the box does not change on browser refresh.

```
    <html>
    <label>Enter an New item to add in Stock</label> <br> </br> <input type="text" name=" itemName" id="addItemInStock"><br></br>
    <p id="errorMsg"></p>
    <button onclick="addToStock()">Add</button>
    <p id="showList"></p>
    <select id="showInDropDown">
            <option  disabled selected style="display: block;">Stock Items</option>
        </select>
    <script>
var fruitsfromLS = localStorage.getItem("fruits");
var fruits = fruitsfromLS ? JSON.parse(fruitsfromLS) : ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
document.getElementById("showList").innerHTML = fruits;
var newItem = document.getElementById("addItemInStock");

function addToStock() {
    if ((newItem.value) === "") {
        document.getElementById("errorMsg").innerHTML = "Blank item cannot be added!!";
        document.getElementById("errorMsg").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("errorMsg").style.display = "none";
        fruits.push(newItem.value);
        //this is added extra
        //  localStorage.setItem("fruits", JSON.stringify(fruits));
        var StoredFruits = localStorage.setItem("fruits", JSON.stringify(fruits));

        document.getElementById("showList").innerHTML = fruits;
        clearAndShow();
    }

    var sel = document.getElementById("showInDropDown");
    document.getElementById("showInDropDown").innerHTML = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
        var opt = document.createElement('option');


        opt.innerHTML = fruits[i];
        opt.value = fruits[i];
        sel.appendChild(opt);
    }
}

function clearAndShow() {
    newItem.value = "";
}
    </script>

    </html>
```

Comment: Since the contents are added dynamically, they tend to loose their values on every page refresh. This is normal behaviour.

Comment: how can we achieve to store those array elements in select box dynamically.

Comment: You should fill it on evry page load then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're only adding the select items in `addToStock`, and it's only called when the button is clicked. Try this

```
<html>
    <label>Enter an New item to add in Stock</label> <br> </br> <input type="text" name=" itemName" id="addItemInStock"><br></br>
    <p id="errorMsg"></p>
    <button onclick="addToStock()">Add</button>
    <p id="showList"></p>
    <select id="showInDropDown">
        <option  disabled selected style="display: block;">Stock Items</option>
    </select>
    <script>
        var fruitsfromLS = localStorage.getItem("fruits");
        var fruits = fruitsfromLS ? JSON.parse(fruitsfromLS) : ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
        document.getElementById("showList").innerHTML = fruits;
        var newItem = document.getElementById("addItemInStock");

        function addToStock() {
            if ((newItem.value) === "") {
                document.getElementById("errorMsg").innerHTML = "Blank item cannot be added!!";
                document.getElementById("errorMsg").style.display = "block";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("errorMsg").style.display = "none";
                fruits.push(newItem.value);
                //this is added extra
                //  localStorage.setItem("fruits", JSON.stringify(fruits));
                var StoredFruits = localStorage.setItem("fruits", JSON.stringify(fruits));

                document.getElementById("showList").innerHTML = fruits;
                clearAndShow();
            }
            fillSelect();

        }

        function fillSelect(){
            var sel = document.getElementById("showInDropDown");
            document.getElementById("showInDropDown").innerHTML = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
                var opt = document.createElement('option');                     
                opt.innerHTML = fruits[i];
                opt.value = fruits[i];
                sel.appendChild(opt);
            }
        }

        function clearAndShow() {
            newItem.value = "";
        }

        window.onload = function(){
            fillSelect();
        };

    </script>
</html>
```

I moved the select-filling code out to its own function, and call it when the page loads using `window.onload`

Comment: isn't there any work around to store the elements in select box directly rather to fill it again on every page load.

Comment: You could use a server side language like PHP to generate the HTML code, but you'd have to store that data somewhere else

Answer (score 1):

You need to call addToStock on page load, for each item in `fruitsfromLS`:

```
(fruitsfromLS || []).forEach(function(fruit) {
   addToStock(fruit)
});
```